# jQuery - Trigger fadeIn() and fadeOut() on different divs

Tags: jquery, fade

I have a parent div and some child divs (a box containing some buttons).

I want to fade a message in when a button is clicked (anywhere in childDivContainer) but I want it to stay visible until the mouse leaves the larger parent area (largerContainer) to prevent the message annoyingly popping up and disappearing all the time, so I have hooked up the fadeOut() to a larger containing div.

However the fadeOut() is being triggered whenever the user mouseOuts from each of the child divs - which is odd because I haven't associated them with the mouseover or anything else.

```
$('#childDivContainer').click(
    function () {
        $("#demoMessage").fadeIn();

    });

$('#largerContainer').mouseout(
    function () {
        $("#demoMessage").fadeOut();
    });


<div id="largerContainer">
   <div id="childDivContainer">
    <div id="childDiv1"></div>
    <div id="childDiv2"></div>
    <div id="childDiv3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.
Simon

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hn43E/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move your cursor over your child divs, it might consider that your mouse is leaving the `largerContainer` and entering your `childDiv`.

You might try to trigger the `fadeOut()` on the `largerContainer`'s parent `mouseenter()` event.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  Strangely though it requires both of these statements (next comment) for the fadeOut work properly.

I had to change the mouseout() to mouseleave() as suggested in previous post (Eric Lemos), and trigger on entering the parent div.  

Without the second statement the fadeOut() only triggered if I mouse out of the parent and then enter it.

I'm not sure exactly what's going on and suspect there could be some bubbling implications as suggested, but it works and it's only for a wireframe so I'm happy as is, thanks all.

Comment: $('#largerContainer').mouseleave(
  function () {
      $("#demoMessage").fadeOut();
  });

    $('#indexTableDiv').mouseenter(
  function () {
      $("#demoMessage").fadeOut();
  });

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `mouseout` to `mouseleave`

**mouseout()**

- When mouse enters the “outerBox”, no event will fire.
- When mouse leaves the “outerBox”, and enters “innerBox”, fire the
  “outerBox”event.
- When mouse leaves the “innerBox”, and enters “outerBox”, fire the
  “innerBox” event, follow by the “outerBox” event.
- When mouseleaves to the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.

**mouseleave()**

- When mouse enters the “outerBox”, no event will fire.
- When mouse leaves the “outerBox”, and enters “innerBox”, no event
  will fire.
- When mouse leaves the “innerBox”, and enters “outerBox”, fire the
  “innerBox” event.
- When mouse leaves to the “outerBox”, fire the “outerBox” event.

**read: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/**

Comment: oh dang this answer is better.  See my answer for historical context of why mouseleave was created :p

Answer (score 0):

When you `mouseout` of the `#child` (and into the `#parent`, the event bubbles thus:

```
2.   #parent -> fire mouseout
       ^
       |
    (mouseout event)
       |
1.    #child -> fire mouseout
```

so with

```
jQuery('#parent, #child').on('mouseout',function(e){
  console.log("mouseout: #" + this.id);
});
```

mousing out of the child would result in

```
> mouseout: #parent
> mouseout: #child
```

**Answer:** You need to play with stopping event propagation (bubbling) and possibly tracking the `mouseover` event on the child (as mousing over the `#child` actually **triggers `mouseout` on the `parent`!**).

Simple example to demonstrate the how the mouseout event is fired http://jsfiddle.net/sequoia/Z9n96/

More complex example I made when working on this sort of problem (play around with attaching/detaching the stop propogation behavior to different events and see how it changes the behavior): http://jsfiddle.net/sequoia/GXmfA/4/